# Macxchange Script to Change MAC and Hostname in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: bash, scripts, perl, backtrack

I'm trying to adapt a script in backtrack to work with ubuntu.  I keep getting an error on line 14 which is the "**if [ $? == 0 ]; then**" line

the script was found on 
http://pctechtips.org/script-to-change-mac-and-hostname-in-backtrack/

the code is below

```
#!/bin/bash
#author: Jorge L. Vazquez
#purpose: this script will change the mac address to random
#and will pick a random word from password.lst in jtr for hostname
#change variables "interface" and "file" to your settings
#also macchanger needs to be installed

INTERFACE=eth0
FILE=/pentest/passwords/jtr/password.lst
WORD=$(sort -R $FILE | head -1)

#changing mac address to random
ifconfig $INTERFACE down > /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    printf "%s\nChanging mac address...\n"
    macchanger -r $INTERFACE
else
    printf "%sScript encounter an error, sorry...\n"
    exit 1
fi

#changing hostname to random word from password.lst
printf "%s\nChanging Hostname...\n"
OLDHOST=$(hostname)
hostname $WORD
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
    printf "%sPrevius Hostname: $OLDHOST \n"
    printf "%sRandom Hostname: $WORD \n"
else
    printf "%sScript encounter an error, sorry...\n"
    exit 1
fi

#putting interface up
ifconfig $INTERFACE up > /dev/null
printf "\n"


#END
```

And the wordlist file for the hostfile (password.lst) looks like this

```
# A couple of merged /etc/hosts files -- 
#
4000ex
a-lhi-bbn-01
a-lhi-sri-03
a00
a1
a2
```

I run the script using sh filename.sh
and i've given it executable access and macchanger is installed but I still get an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sh is not bash, so don't run a bash script with sh. Run it with either `./filename` (requires that the script is executable, and uses the shebang) or `bash ./filename` (only requires the script to be readable, and the shebang is ignored).

It's also not a good idea to use extensions for scripts, especially not `.sh` when the script is not an sh script.

The script itself uses POSIX sh compatible syntax, with the exception of the `[` command which have no `==` operator in POSIX. To compare two strings for equality with the `[` command, the operator is `=`. `[ "$?" = 0 ]`.

That said, testing whether `$?` is 0 or not is a bit pointless. It's better to just test the command directly, rather than run the command, then run another command to determine if the previous command succeeded.

```
if ifconfig "$interface" down > /dev/null; then
    ...
else
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Thanks geirha that helped but when I check the connection information using ubuntu 12.04 in the networking gui to verify I noticed the hardward address does not change. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: @RickT maybe macchanger is not installed? What does `type macchanger` output?

Comment: Geirha it's installed and it changes the Hardware Address in the terminal window (I checked using ifconfig) but it doesn't change in the ubuntu networking gui

Comment: I did type macchanger and this output came out GNU MAC Changer
Usage: macchanger [options] device

Try `macchanger --help' for more options.

Comment: @RickT ah, so Network Manager doesn't detect the change? perhaps try restarting network manager: `sudo restart network-manager`

Comment: geirha correct any changes I make with ifconfig seems to get over written by ubuntu's network-manager process.

Comment: @RickT Try using `nmcli` to disable/enable the interface, instead of using `ifconfig`

Comment: thanks geirha I gave it a try with info from this page http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=1163023.

To see the status of a connection you can go:
nmcli con status id 'Wired connection 1'

To bring down the interface and disconnect you'd go:
nmcli con down id 'Wired connection 1'
nmcli dev disconnect iface eth0

to bring it back up:
nmcli con up id 'Wired connection 1'

It didn't work but I'm still searching